# How can I close this PHP session_start(); without losing functionality?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Let's start by saying I'm not a PHP expert.

Wordpress doesn't use Sessions by design, but I have a plugin I'm using that allows users to log in via Azure Active Directory... that plugin typically has them log in on the normal Wordpress login page, but we have added a login link on another page (one with classroom/tutorials).

The plugin we are using: https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress

In redirecting users to the login from a page other than the main Wordpress login page, it throws an antiforgery_ID mismatch error. So I used the suggestion from this thread on that plugin's Github to run it in a session:
https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress/issues/159

So my code looks like this:

```
function sess_start() {
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
}
add_action('init','sess_start');

add_action(
    'learndash-login-modal-after',
    function() {
        $stored_settings = get_option( 'aadsso_settings', null );
        $aad= AADSSO::get_instance($stored_settings);
        $loginUrl = $aad->get_login_url();
        echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Sign in with your AAD account</a>';
    }
);
```

It works. But now Wordpress's site health is telling me:
"An active PHP session was detected.
A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests."

Ok... so I try closing the session by adding to the end:

```
function sess_close() {
 session_write_close();
}
add_action('init','sess_close');
```

And it throws the antiforgery_ID mismatch errors again (which I'm guessing means it is closing the session before returning any values back to the login form).

So... how can I run this code and store the value in a way that still allows me to close the session and make Wordpress happy? Or is something else going on here that is over my head?

Comment: Have you tried hooking `shutdown` instead of `init`...?

Comment: @esqew shutdown would be too late, ie. would close the session only after all scripts are done, which will cause a lot of problems. (ie. hanging page loads, problems mentioned in the WP site health, etc)

Comment: @esqew, Kaii is right... didn't work. Still throws the error on site health.